# All data insert one to another table using C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I have Two Table one name is Table_1 and second is Table_2.

My Database name is "Test_1" and i have Two Table.
In "Table_1" only contain one Column name is "col" and in "Table_2" first column is "ID" and second is "col".
I want that When I Click on "Button1" all Data of "Table_1" is insert into "Table_2" with "ID" is "TextBox1".
I don't know, How to achieve this Problem.
I am using ASP.Net C# and SQL Server 2008.

Here is my ASPX Code :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default3.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default3" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="ID"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="TextBox1">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: could you be more clear

Comment: @syedmohsin please ask what you can't understand.

Comment: use jquery and onclick action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Solution :

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select * from Table_1", con);
SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

string test = "";
while (reader.Read())
{
    test = reader["col"].ToString();

    SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand("insert into Table_2 values(@ID,@col)", con);
    com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", TextBox1.Text);
    com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col", test);
    com1.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this SQL query on button click in your code

> 1. make a string

```
  string qry="INSERT INTO Table_2 (ID, col)"+
    " SELECT ('"+TextBox1.Text+"',col)"+
    " FROM Table_1";
```

> 2. Run this query.It will copy all record with same id as in the TextBox1.

#### Apply validation on TextBox1.If you allready done that no need to read below part :)

### Cons of this method

> If user will enter the value of id then you have to check on SQL injection attack.Otherwise you can trust your user.:)
>   If you make dynamic query then there will chance of SQL Injection attack.
>
> #### I cannot explain what is sql injection here.

### Prevention from this attack

> Use proper validation. If you are using proper validation at client side and server side then user will not be able to enter any special symbol (;,'',' etc). So it will directly remove this attack.
>
> Secondly you can use some code for filter. Like if user enters some
>   sql code then you have to check that at server side first. When user
>   input data passes the filtration and it is correct string then only
>   run the query

Comment: i don't want to insert TextBox1 as String I want to insert Value of TextBox1.Text

Comment: So you want to same Id as in textbox1 to be added with all record in table_2 ?

Comment: or you want different different id for each record?

Comment: yes only I want to same Id as in textbox1 to be added with all record in table_2.